Django User-roles permission
I’m trying to create a school management webapp using Django. I’m using PostgreSQL for database. The webapp will be used by many schools that’s why am trying django_tenant. Kindly advise on how I should go about the account app that should handle login and signup from main homepage. Users are to be link to their respective schools so as other data for security purposes. I have several users like student, parent, teacher, treasurer, manager, and secretary for each school. I want to end up assigning roles for each user that is different from other users something that I need to be handled by using user_type while signing up. But also I want to have other fields in the signup form specific to the user like parent for student. Kindly advise.
I try using AbstractUser but since I also want added fields per user am trying customuserform. The two don’t seem to work well together.

Can you elaborate further with code examples? Like your models.py, views.py, and or forms.py where your challenge is coming from?
